# How to compile and run a simple java file in jenkins on Windows

Tags: java, windows, compilation, jenkins

I have installed Jenkins on Windows and created a job in Jenkins. I want to compile and execute a simple java file (say Hello.java). How can I do that?

My Hello.java contains the following code:

```
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("I'm dancing");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you already set up version control? Normally the process is: 1. create your project and a build script for your project 1. Setup version control and check in source and build script 2. Setup your project in Jenkins to monitor the repository and start a build when a checkin is detected.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Go to configuration page of your job/project
2. Select "Execute Windows batch command" from "Add build step" combo
3. Type the following on Command field:
   javac Hello.java
   java Hello
4. Save configuration
5. Keep Hello.java on the folder /Jenkins/workspace/
6. Build the project/job by clicking "Build Now" link and see the Console Output

Comment: The above answer is nice for me

Comment: Step#3 is not supported in ubuntu. Can any body explain what command will we run on ubuntu?

Comment: @user3141034 : It is the step to compile and then run the java file. You can do it the same way you compile it in the terminal.
compile your program using: javac Hello.java 
and then run using java Hello

Comment: Hello, 
In real world, the java file is not under the repo locationm but might be under \src\ folder. 
I did javac src\Hello.java and it worked ok.
But for the java src\Hello I got an error.
Please kindly advise

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Maven for automatic builds on a continuous integration server such as Jenkins: http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/public-book.html

There is even an exec Plugin which allows you to execute a Java program using Maven, but this is rarely needed on a continuous integration server.

Comment: This is a nice tutorial about Maven