# Unable to execute java program in jenkins?

Tags: java, jenkins

I am trying to execute simple java class through jenkins and i have followed below post but no results,please help how to execute complete java program in jenkins.

[How to compile and run a simple java file in jenkins on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020034/how-to-compile-and-run-a-simple-java-file-in-jenkins-on-windows)

Always getting error as

```
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Run Java Class
[Run Java Class] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson7739288570136427109.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Run Java Class>javac "E:\Java_Tutorials\JavaPractices\src\com\practice\javsSuperCars.java" 
javac: file not found: E:\Java_Tutorials\JavaPractices\src\com\practice\javsSuperCars.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Run Java Class>java SuperCars 
Error: Could not find or load main class SuperCars

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Run Java Class>exit 1 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

The post that you referred was a sample example where the Java class that was executed was on the Jenkins Workspace folder directly, but your application is different as it is with a project folder structure.

Jenkins doesn't identify your Main class without you adding it to the CLASSPATH implicitly. Here the necessity of setting the CLASSPATH is more important.

In the **Execute Windows batch Command** section, you need to traverse to your Main class and then you need to issue the command to compile the same.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please provide some example with some simple steps,unable to understand clearly.