# Convert Maven Project to Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible to convert Maven Project to Jenkins (I want to convert all the project from Maven to Jenkins)
My organization does not want to use Maven any more. The project has to be completely in Jenkins. 
Please let me know the process of converting the project. 
Thank you.

Comment: `Maven` is a build tool and `Jenkins` is just an orchestration tool that leverages a build tool such as `Maven` to get the job done. Jenkins can be made to work with other build tools such as `ant` (or) `gradle`. So what do you mean convert a `Maven` project to `Jenkins` ? Can you please elaborate as to what you are looking for ?

Comment: So currently we have all the projects created in Maven. Now my organization wants that all the configuration or projects should be in Jenkins, without any dependency with build tool such as Maven.

Comment: Thank you Krishnan for the information.

Answer (score 0):

As Krishnan said in the comments, Jenkins is not a build tool. Jenkins is a build server that is meant for invoking build tools like Maven. It doesn't replace build tools.

So your question of converting Maven to Jenkins doesn't really make sense, since they are doing different things. However, if you are for some reason unable to use Maven, you have some alternatives. Some I can think of:

- Use [Gradle](https://gradle.org/)
- Use [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) (only recommended for simply structured projects with little to no dependencies)
- Use command line calls with plain javac like this: [How to compile and run a simple java file in jenkins on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020034/how-to-compile-and-run-a-simple-java-file-in-jenkins-on-windows) (not recommended since you have to script everything a build tool does yourself)