# Cannot find class in classpath - TestNG with Linux via Jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, testng

Folder structure:

[image]

Build step details:

[image]

Jenkins console output:

```
+ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_171"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b10, mixed mode)
+ uname -a
Linux jenkins2.spikes.eng 2.6.32-754.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jun 19 21:26:04 
UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
+ id
uid=498(jenkins) gid=498(jenkins) groups=498(jenkins) 
context=system_u:system_r:unconfined_java_t:s0
+ pwd
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing
+ cd CC_Regression
+ chmod -R 777 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression
+ java -cp './bin:./lib/*' org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
[TestNG] [ERROR] 
Cannot find class in classpath: testCases.LoginPage
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

testng.xml

```
<suite name="Suite">
<test name="Test">
<classes>
<class name="testCases.LoginPage"/>
<class name="testCases.Forgot_Password"/>
<class name="testCases.Dashboards"/>
</classes>
<classes>...</classes>
</test>
<test name="Test">...</test>
<!-- Test -->
</suite>
<suite name="Suite">...</suite>
<!-- Suite -->
```

Note: 
1) added chmod as earlier was getting permission denied.

Please suggest what went wrong

Comment: `java -cp './bin:./lib/*' org.testng.TestNG testng.xml` does this work fine when you run it on your command line ?? not inside jenkins

Comment: tried below too via Jenkins
export CLASSPATH=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/bin:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/*

java org.testng.TestNG /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/testng.xml

Comment: I meant run the above command on "command prompt" on your desktop does that work fine ??

Comment: yes it is working

Comment: Can you confirm if the class files are generated in the workspace in jenkins ??

Comment: Hey Rohit, Sorry forgot to update the thread. Yeah class files were missing in the workspace. after uploading the class file it worked fine. Thank you :)

Comment: So the what is happening is that your project is not getting built in jenkins :) if possible convert it into a maven project and the build can be done on jenkins side and the class files will be generated ....or you have to do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020034/how-to-compile-and-run-a-simple-java-file-in-jenkins-on-windows

Comment: Yeah. Maven is something which i am planning now as stuck with another issue. Will create a new thread. Please see if you can help me on that too..